# How to extract part from string?

Tags: r

If I have this string:

`bb=c("\\dat\\Bjkjgf_Yloiut_dsezr_proj_111_999.txt","\\dat\\Bjkjgf_Yloezr_proj_111_999.txt")`

I need to extract whatever between   \\ and _proj

i can do this, but will work for one and not the other:

`substr(bb, 1, 15)`

the expected output

Bjkjgf_Yloiut_dsezr,Bjkjgf_Yloezr

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: You might want to check out the `basename()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `gsub`

```
gsub(".*\\\\|_proj.*", "", bb)
[1] "Bjkjgf_Yloiut_dsezr" "Bjkjgf_Yloezr"
```

Answer (score 0):

With `regmatches`:

```r
sapply(regmatches(bb, regexec("dat\\\\(.*)_proj", bb)), `[`, 2)
#[1] "Bjkjgf_Yloiut_dsezr" "Bjkjgf_Yloezr"
```

Or `stringr::str_match`:

```r
stringr::str_match(bb, "dat\\\\(.*)_proj")[, 2]
```